# SourceSansPro-Bold font bolder in firefox

Tags: css

In Firefox:

[image: display in firefox]

```
.enum{
font-family: "SourceSansPro-Bold","Source Sans Pro";
font-weight: 700;
}
```

If I am doing font-weight: 400 than it is fine

```
.enum{
font-family: "SourceSansPro-Bold","Source Sans Pro";
font-weight: 400;
}
```

But when if user has the google fonts CDN blocked than it looks vary no bold

[image: Not bold]

```
.enum{
font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download the bold version as well.

with this tag in your html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
```

If it gets blocked, there's nothing much you can do

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it for firefox like that. it will handle only for firefox browser. you can set this hack for only firefox browser.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.enum{
      font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
      font-weight: 400;
 }
}
```